# How to delete a pointer created in a function and as the return value

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class AAA{
}

class BBB{
public:
   AAA* doSomething(){
      return new AAA();
   }
}
```

I created and returned a pointer with NEW in a function in class BBB, I want to know whether I should delete it somewhere. If I should, then how can I achieve that? I have some experience in Java, but I am a total newbie in C++, please help me.

Sorry, I think I did not describe my problem well.
Suppose I have to write a function which concatenate two char[sizeA] and char[sizeB]. So I think I should do something like this:

```
char* concatenate(char* str1, char* str2, int sizeA, int sizeB){
   char* temp = new char[sizeA + sizeB - 1];
   ...
   return temp;
}
```

This is what I would do in Java, but I don't how to do it in C. I don't who is gonna use this returned char[] so I don't know where to write the "delect" code.

Comment: That's the right question. C++ won't clean up objects that you create with `new` for you. That's an important difference between Java and C++. As @LuchianGrigore points out, you often don't need to create objects with `new`.

Comment: Outside of smart pointers, you should consider `new` to mean "*I am explicitly saying that I want to manage the lifetime of this object*".

Comment: is this HW?? if not just use **std::string**, cancat string is as simply as **str3 = str1 + str2**.

Comment: char* is C style.
If you want your own string then why not to make it a class/template?
And have the length as a member? Then you can overload the operater+() to concatinate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to delete a pointer is using `delete` :

```
BBB b;
AAA *a = b.doSomething();

// ...

delete a;
```

But if you want make it safer use can use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

However in C++ you don't have to `new` a variable as a pointer. You can create an object and return it:

```
class BBB{
public:
    AAA doSomething() { 
       return AAA();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a pointer, so why use a pointer? What's wrong with

```
AAA doSomething()
{
   return AAA();
}
```

If you must, return a `std::unique_ptr`.

If you really want to use raw pointers, just `delete` the result.

Comment: @Nawaz I thought that was non-copyable.

Comment: It will be *moved*, not *copied*. (`unique_ptr` is moveable).

Comment: [See this](http://ideone.com/LaSPS0). the local `unique_ptr` will be moved automatically (even without `std::move`).

Comment: The right thing to do would be to return a `unique_ptr`. `shared_ptr` can be constructed from a `unique_ptr&&`, so he can still use `shared_ptr`s to store the result of that function.

Answer (score 0):

since your background is java. please read about parameter by value, by reference and by pointer.

```
AAA doSomething()
{
   return AAA();
}
```

you can create this function inside class B.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know who is going to use the pointer you created, the best way is to transfer the ownership of the pointer (and thus, the responsibility to delete it) to the client of your class.

There are several way to do so. The simplest one is to use `std::auto_ptr`. This way, the code using your function will gain the pointer ownership upon using your function and the destruction of the `std::auto_ptr` variable on the client code side will lead to the deletion of the pointer you created.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is bad; that is why it is **deprecated** in C++11.